# geom_rect not working with scale_y_log10() (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(economics) + 
geom_rect(
  aes(
    xmin = economics$date[20], 
    xmax = economics$date[140], 
    ymin = -Inf, 
    ymax = Inf
  ), 
  fill = "grey", 
  color = "grey", 
  alpha = 0.4
) + 
geom_line(aes(x = date, y = pce))
```

works fine and produces the desired plot. But if one were to transform the y-axis to log10 (by using scale_y_log10())

```
ggplot(economics) + 
geom_rect(
  aes(
    xmin = economics$date[20], 
    xmax = economics$date[140], 
    ymin = -Inf, 
    ymax = Inf
  ), 
  fill = "grey", 
  color = "grey", 
  alpha = 0.4
) + 
geom_line(aes(x = date, y = pce)) + 
scale_y_log10()
```

it gives the following error:

**Warning messages: 

1: In self$trans$transform(x) : NaNs produced 

2: Removed 574 rows containing missing values (geom_rect).**

and removes the geom_rect layer.

Comment: Do you have negative values?

Comment: just change `ymin` to `0`