# background fill (via geom_rect) is removed after scale_y_log10 transformation

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add a background fill to a plot created with grouped data (factor x axis) and a log-scale y axis. When the log-scale is added, the background fill is removed.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

**Reproducible Example data:**
I'll use the `mtcars` data, but with the `cyl` variable as a factor. This is the simplest dataset that mimics my data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
mtcars_f <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(cyl.f = factor(cyl))
```

This works fine with a normal y-axis scale.

```
mtcars_f %>% 
  ggplot(aes(cyl.f, mpg)) +
  geom_rect(xmin=-Inf, ymin=17.5, xmax=Inf, ymax=22.5) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

**The Problem:**
However, the background rectangle fill is removed when the y-axis is transformed:

```
mtcars_f %>% 
  ggplot(aes(cyl.f, mpg)) +
  geom_rect(xmin=-Inf, ymin=17.5, xmax=Inf, ymax=22.5) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_log10()
```

[image]

note: this is a different issue than [this similarly titled question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35197640/geom-rect-not-working-with-scale-y-log10-ggplot2)

**EDIT with answer:** The answer by @Tung works! This can also be worked around by passing the data to `geom_rect` as an aesthetic, and you specify the x-axis as "discrete"

```
rect_df <- 
  data_frame(xmin=-Inf, ymin=17.5, xmax=Inf, ymax=22.5)
mtcars_f %>% 
  ggplot(aes(cyl.f, mpg)) +
  geom_rect(data = rect_df, aes(xmin=xmin, ymin=ymin, xmax=xmax, ymax=ymax), inherit.aes = F) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_log10() +
  scale_x_discrete()
```

Comment: I've figured out the rectangle is still there, it's just outside the plot limits. When data is passed to `geom_rect` outside of a dataframe and the proper mapping with `aes()` the numbers are altered when the scale is changed. It can be seen after adding to the scale command: `scale_y_log10(limits = c(0.05, 1e+25))`

Comment: To work around this, pass the data like I've edited in my answer or the answer by @Tung below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a workaround using `annotate` until you find out what went wrong for `geom_rect`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mtcars_f <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(cyl.f = factor(cyl)) 

mtcars_f %>% 
  ggplot(aes(cyl.f, mpg)) +
  scale_y_log10() +
  scale_x_discrete() +
  annotate(geom = "rect", 
           xmin = -Inf, ymin = 17.5, xmax = Inf, ymax = 22.5,
           fill = "light blue", alpha = 0.8) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_classic(base_size = 12)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-08-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).

Comment: Thanks! this indeed looks like the preferred way to do it.

Comment: Alternatively, I get the same result when using similar notation and passing the data in a dataframe to an aes. The issue is that data passed to `geom_rect` outside of `aes()` are not transformed. I found that comment by Hadley in a ggplot issue- that is actually the preferred behavior and won't be changed.